# In C, how to indicate EOF after writing data without close/shutdown a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, keep-alive

I am new to C socket programming. I learned that after sending data through a socket, one should either `close` or `shutdown` the socket descriptor, which triggers an EOF to be sent to the other end. Without an EOF, `read`/`recv` keeps blocking.

Now I am wondering if it is possible at all to keep the socket open for further data transfer. From what I read, this seems to be what people do when they establish a keep-alive HTTP connection. But I could not figure out how this is achieved.

The following code shows the scenario, which stuck after the client's `write`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define thread_printf(...) printf("[PID %d] ", getpid()); printf(__VA_ARGS__);

int create_socket()
{
  int socket_fd;
  socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (socket_fd < 0)
    perror("Error opening socket");
  return socket_fd;
}

int listen_port(int portno)
{
  int socket_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

  socket_fd = create_socket();

  memset((void *) &server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    perror("Error on binding");

  listen(socket_fd, 5);
  return socket_fd;
}

int connect_port(const char *host, int portno)
{
  int socket_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in proxy_addr;
  struct hostent *proxy;

  socket_fd = create_socket();

  proxy = gethostbyname(host);
  if (proxy == NULL)
    perror("Error no such host");

  proxy_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  proxy_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
  memcpy((void *) &proxy_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, (void *) proxy->h_addr, proxy->h_length);

  if (connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &proxy_addr, sizeof(proxy_addr)) < 0)
    perror("Error connecting");

  return socket_fd;
}

int read_socket(int fd, char *buf, int bufsize)
{
  thread_printf("read_socket\n");
  int m = 0;                    /* total number of bytes received */
  int n = 0;                    /* number of bytes received in a single read */

  while (m < bufsize - 1)
  {
    n = read(fd, buf + m, bufsize - m - 1);
    if (n == -1)                /* socket read error */
    {
      perror("Error reading socket");
      break;
    }
    if (n == 0)                 /* socket is closed */
      break;
    m += n;
  }

  if (m >= bufsize)
    perror("Error buffer overflow");

  buf[m] = '\0';
  return m;
}

int write_socket(int fd, char *buf, int len)
{
  thread_printf("write_socket\n");
  int m = 0;
  int n = 0;

  while (m < len)
  {
    n = write(fd, buf + m, len - m);
    if (n == -1) {
      perror("Error socket send");
      break;
    }
    if (n == 0)                 /* socket is closed */
      break;
    m += n;
  }
  thread_printf("m = %d, len = %d\n", m, len);
  return m;
}

int main()
{
  int socket_fd = listen_port(3129);
  if (fork() == 0)              /* client */
  {
    close(socket_fd);
    int client_socket_fd = connect_port("127.0.0.1", 3129);
    int n;
    char *msg = "This is a client request\n";
    char buf[1024];
    memset((void *) buf, 0, 1024);
    n = write_socket(client_socket_fd, msg, strlen(msg));
    thread_printf("client sent: %s\n", msg);
    n = read_socket(client_socket_fd, buf, 1024);
    thread_printf("client received: %s\n", buf);
    close(client_socket_fd);
  }
  else                          /* server */
  {
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int client_len;
    client_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    int client_socket_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &client_len);
    int n;
    char *msg = "This is a server response\n";
    char buf[1024];
    n = read_socket(client_socket_fd, buf, 1024);
    thread_printf("server received: %s\n", buf);
    n = write_socket(client_socket_fd, msg, strlen(msg));
    thread_printf("server sent: %s\n", msg);
    close(client_socket_fd);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: HTTP keep-alive requires `Content-Length` headers or chunks so you know where the next response starts.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Ryan. It makes more sense to me to after reading what `Content-Length` and `Transfer-Encoding` mean and how they are used.

Comment: OT: The last parameter passed to `accept()` has to be the address of a `socklen_t` not of an `int`. Also `read()` and `write()` return `ssize_t` not `int`.

Answer (score 4):

In server your code waits to read 1024 bytes but in client you are sending only 26 bytes as `strlen(msg)`, so your server will never return from `read_socket`

As for any socket  client-server application, you need to define your own protocol for client and server as when to conclude all data has been read, either by deciding fixed length packets or by including length of data as part of data itself

e.g. You can decide your data will include, first 2 bytes as length of data followed by actual data

Comment: Thanks @Pras. Now I realize that I misunderstood what the last argument of `read` means. So unless it is signaled an EOF, `read` will block until it grabs the specified number of bytes. Is that right?

Comment: It may return for lesser data as well, but you are makeing another recv call to read more data and client is not sending any, thats making it block in next recv

Answer (score 4):

> Now I am wondering if it is possible at all to keep the socket open
>   for further data transfer.

Yes, absolutely -- in general, you can keep the socket open for as long as you want, and you can send (and/or receive) as much data as you like.

The receiver will in most cases need some way to unambiguously parse the incoming data, though -- in particular it needs to have some way to know when one semantic "message" (*) ends and the next one begins.  If you only send one "message" and then close the TCP connection, this issue is avoided since the EOF itself serves as your end-of-message indicator, but if you're going to hold the connection open for more than one message you will need some way for the receiver to determine where the message-boundary lies.

This information needs to be encoded in the data itself, since the TCP protocol makes no promises about how many bytes it will deliver to the receiving process during each call to recv(); it only guarantees that the bytes will be received in the same order they were sent.

Common methods for encoding message-boundary information include:

1. Prepending the message with a short fixed-size header that indicates how many bytes to expect in the message body
2. Designating a special "end-of-message" character such as a NUL byte or a carriage return (note that if you do this, you need to make sure that either your messages never contain this character as part of the payload data, or that if they do it is suitably escaped somehow so that it is not mistakenly interpreted as a message-boundary)
3. [SLIP encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol) (or similar)
4. Requiring all messages to be a well-known, fixed size (this is appropriate only for certain use cases)

I personally prefer method (1) as I find it the easiest to implement correctly and efficiently, but any of the above can work.

(*) "message" in this context is defined as "the number of bytes that the receiver needs to read in before it can react to their meaning in some useful way"

Comment: #4 is arguably even easier to implement correctly, but has a major drawback: it won't be possible to maintain backwards compatibility when extending the protocol.

Comment: correctly, yes; efficiently, perhaps not, unless your message are always at or near your chosen message-size (or slightly smaller)